# After deleting my table I changed in MySQL query then again is not creating table

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created table then I deleted it and then after changing in my sql query, my module is not creating table. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

Find in core_resource table value with name of your module, then delete this value. Better create dump before any actions.

Answer (score 0):

Every time magento check module version in core_resource 
If version doesn't match, then Magento check SQL script in the SQL - setup folder

If you delete table from database manually, then you need to change value or delete value for your module in **core_resource** table and clean cache